# Can Jenkins job execute shell or Windows command conditionally based on agent OS?

Tags: linux, windows, shell, batch-file, jenkins

I'm trying to build a job that will execute a program on remote agents. The program is either exe when agent is on Windows or shell script when it is on Linux. The program is already deployed on agent machines. I'm looking for a solution that would allow me to conditionally run either exe (Execute Windows batch command) or shell (Execute shell) depending on the agent's OS.

So far I found there is a run condition plugin (https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Run+Condition+Plugin), whuch would be great, unfortunatelly it does not have check for agent's OS.

Is there any way to accomplish that? Google tells me nothing.

Comment: if you can rename files you can 'hack' the jenkins. As windows have pathext variable you can run .exe and .bat files without pointing their extension. So if on windows the program has name `someprogram.sh.exe` or `someprogram.sh.bat`   and on Unix `someprogram.sh` probably you'll be able to run it on both systems by calling just `someprogram.sh`

Answer (score 3):

Found something that seems to work:

https://www.techiepie.com/2016/04/14/how-to-identify-jenkins-slave-operating-system-in-a-build/

- Add Conditional Build Step – Single or Multiple.
- In Run? Condition select “Execute Shell” and enter command echo "IsShell"
- Provide Linux Shell Commands as Steps to run if condition is met.
- Add another Conditional Build Step – Single or Multiple.
- In Run? Condition Select “Execute Windows Batch Commands” and enter command echo "IsWindows"
- Provide Windows batch commands as Steps to run if condition is met.

Answer (score 1):

The solution that I found that avoids any exceptions in the output is:

For Windows, compare that these strings match:

```
${ENV,var="OS"}
Windows_NT
```

For Linux, compare that these strings match:

```
${ENV,var="OS"}
```

(The second string is left blank.)

Comment: Worked for me as well.